# Unix Basis echo in for loop

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Hello iam just new in `shell/bash` and I cant explain why my code:

```
#!/bin/sh
adresses=$(seq 1 255)
for i in "$adresses"
do
Adr=$(echo "192.168.0.$i")
echo "$Adr"
done
```

producing this output:
    `192.168.0.1 2 3 4 ...........255`

I really expect 
    `192.168.0.1 192.168.0.2 ...and so on`

If someone can explain me why? not how to do it other way.
Thank you.

Comment: Btw.: replace `Adr=$(echo "192.168.0.$i")` by `Adr="192.168.0.$i"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting protects whitespaces. Replace

```
for i in "$adresses"
```

by

```
for i in $adresses
```

Comment: And better use an array, or better don't bother with the variable at all and even better don't use `seq` and just use `for i in {1..255}`.

Comment: Or `for Adr in 192.168.0.{1..255}; do echo $Adr; done`. And if you simply want to echo all of these addresses separated by space you can `echo 192.168.0.{1..255}`.